# Jersey jarhell - v2.22.1, all dependencies added

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, weblogic

I'm trying to configure a basic java web application to use Jersey, I've followed a number of different tutorials: mkyong's, poor developer's, the jersey documentation for dependencies, and I'm stuck.

I've also made sure all of my Jersey libs are downloaded/located at **web/WEB-INF/lib**, and all jar versions are legit.

**This is web/WEB-INF/lib:**

[image]

**Web.XML :**

[image]

**Stack Trace:**

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:216)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:211)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
```

Comment: Looks like your WebLogic is using a different version of JAX-RS (1.x version).

Comment: any idea how could I change the version of JAX-RS my WebLogic is using? it's a new, 12.1.3 server.
Anyhow, the version that I'm using (that shows up at the **web/WEB-INF/lib** path) is the 2.x version, is it not?

Comment: I don't use WebLogic, so I am not sure what exactly is going on, but the `Application` class that is getting loaded is an older 1.x version (which doesn't have a `getProperties()` method). The application is trying to access a 2.x `Application` class which is not the one that is loaded, that's the reason for the error.

Comment: By the way, you can actually see that the function getProperties() actually exists in javax.ws.rs.core.Application, here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Bg7KK.png

Comment: The `Application` class in your project, and the actual one class loaded may not be the same, if there is an older on on the classpath. If the older one is not in your project, then the only other explanation is that it is from the server

Comment: The WebLogic server is a local one that I'm running.

Comment: I've just made sure every dependency matches, and redownloaded the javax.ws.rs.core jar from maven, made sure it's in WEB-INF/lib, to no avail - the exception prevails.

Comment: I think you are missing the point I am making. You may need to do some research on class loading and how it works to understand the problem. You app uses JAX-RS 2.0. But the server seems to have JAX-RS 1.x. When your app loads, the `Application` class object in your lib, is not the one class loaded. Instead it is the `Application` class that is already on the server. The older one that gets loaded is not compatible with JAX-RS 2.0. Without having to understand all the details of class loading, I'd say look for a way to disable or upgrade the JAX-RS version the server is using.

Comment: Or just use the version the server is using. In which case, all your jars should be only compile-time jars (i.e not loaded to the server). But you need to configure your app to be compatible with the version the server is using. I don't use WebLogic, otherwise I would try and help you do one of the two.

Comment: Or, if you can, use a non EE server, like Tomcat, that doesn't have a JAX-RS implementation, so you are free to use whatever implementation you want, without having to worry about upgrades and such

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use any other server other than WebLogic.
I followed the tutorial at https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/RESTF/use-jersey20-ri.htm#RESTF292, same error. I tried specifying `<prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>`, adding a `library-ref` to jax-rs v2 or v2.5, and still the error persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the way, moving to TomCat perfectly solved this problem. 
I tried peeskillet's suggestions that appeared in the comments above, yet nothing worked.

I gave up on WLS and everything worked.